# LINQ query to return grandparents that grandkids match value

Tags: c#, linq

The idea is to return a list of grandparents who have grandkids with the name of 'Bob'

```
List<GrandParent> g_rents = new List<GrandParent>();

class GrandParent
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Parent> l_rents { get; set; }

   public GrandParent()
   {
      l_rents = new List<Parent>();
   }

}

class Parent
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Child> l_kids { get; set; }

   public Parent()
   {
       l_kids = new List<Child>();
   }

}

class Child
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I've tried 2 different queries:

```
   var y = g_rents.Where( p => p.l_rents.l_kids.Any(o => o.Name == "Bob") );
```

Has an error of:

```
'List<Parent>' does not contain a definition for 'l_kids' and no accessible extension method     'l_kids' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Parent>'
```

This query:

```
   var x = g_rents.Where(g => g.l_rents.Where(h => h.l_kids.Select(i => i.Name=="Bob"));
```

Had an error of:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'bool'
```

I use LINQ just enough to know I'm probably missing something simple in them, but I can't figure out what.

thank you!

Comment: You need `Any` on the `l_rents` as well in your first attempt

Comment: Hi, Lee. Don't be afraid to use more letters when describing properties within the classes.  For example, you can use `KidsList` instead of `l_kids`. It's more readable, and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks CoolBots!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoolBots is right. You need an `.Any()` in there. This is what I did, but now I realize the `Where`'s are unnecessary. I'd go with CoolBots' answer.

```
 var grandParents = g_rents.Where(gp => gp.l_rents
                             .Where(p => p.l_kids
                               .Where(k => k.Name.Equals("Bob")).Any())
                              .Any()).ToList();
```

I had no idea you could throw a lambda in `Any`. The more you know...

Comment: Lol! Imagine the accepted answer is the one that says mine is right!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there; you need `Any` on the `l_rents` as well:

```cs
g_rents.Where(g => g.l_rents.Any(p => p.l_kids.Any(k => k.Name == "Bob")));
```

The logic being, "for each grandparent `g` in the grandparents list `g_rents`, return those `Where` `Any` parent `p` in that grandparent's `g` parents list `g.l_rents` has `Any` kid `k` in that respective parent's kids list `p.l_kids`, who  is named "Bob" (`k.Name == "Bob"`).